# Mapnik renders almost blank image when rendering 2 layers

Tags: python, mapnik

From Python code I can get Mapnik to render this PNG image:

[image]

And this one:

[image]

But if I try to render both these layers (to render the dots on top of the basemap), then I get only this PNG - which is all transparent; but showing a "half dot" at the bottom. Almost is if the image is rendered but the clipping is wrong:

[image]

There are no error messages or other clues. What can I be doing wrong? I sense something fuzzy with unaligned projections; but I am not sure.

The Python code looks like this:

```
import mapnik
mapnik.logger.set_severity(mapnik.severity_type.Debug)

# Base map
map = mapnik.Map(1600, 1200)

# Create raster and point symbolizers
raster = mapnik.RasterSymbolizer()

point = mapnik.PointSymbolizer()
point.file = 'dot.png'
point.allow_overlap = True

# Create new rules and add the symbolizers
raster_rule = mapnik.Rule()
raster_rule.symbols.append(raster)

point_rule = mapnik.Rule()
point_rule.symbols.append(point)

# Create new styles and add the rules
raster_style = mapnik.Style()
raster_style.rules.append(raster_rule)

point_style = mapnik.Style()
point_style.rules.append(point_rule)

# Add the styles to the map
map.append_style('Raster style', raster_style)
map.append_style('Point style', point_style)

# Specify our data sources
raster_datasource = mapnik.Gdal(file='K100_2017_1_20_612_62.tif')
point_datasource = mapnik.Datasource(type='csv',file='stats.csv')

# Create new layers for the map, add the data sources and styles to those layers.
raster_layer = mapnik.Layer('Raster')
raster_layer.datasource = raster_datasource
raster_layer.srs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +over'
raster_layer.styles.append('Raster style')

point_layer = mapnik.Layer('Point')
point_layer.datasource = point_datasource
point_layer.srs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +over'
point_layer.styles.append('Point style')

# Add the layers to the map

# If both of these two lines are active - a blank image is rendered?
# If just one of them (any) - and image is rendered fine?
map.layers.append(raster_layer)
map.layers.append(point_layer)

map.srs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +over'
map.zoom_all()
mapnik.render_to_file(map, 'K100_2017_1_20_612_62-base-pos.png', 'png32:z=1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Using gdalsrsinfo I discovered the srs of the basemap to be `+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`.

So changing the right-hand-side of this line fixed the issue:

```
raster_layer.srs = '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'
```

I can now render this:

[image]